# Combining two lists in an odd order

Tags: python

I am writing a script that when you put in a buisness name, it gets the phone number and address for the place.

Unfortunately the phone numbers and adresses are in different lists, and I need to figure out how to combine the lists with a sort of a 'Go here, skip one, go here" sort of thing.

EXAMPLE:

```
i = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l = ['1', '2', '3']
```

How could I combine these so it becomes

```
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c']
```

Comment: Are you sure you want this structure? It's a very odd way to store these data. I suggest a `dict`: `phones = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.

Comment: I'd recommend a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
i = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l = ['1', '2', '3']

for j,k in zip(l,i):
    result.extend((j,k))
```

Output:

```
>>> result
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c']
```

Comment: An even nicer way would be `itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(i, l))`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the two lists and insert each of its elements in a new list following the desired order.

```
 a=len(i)-1  #len-1 because i used range which goes until n-1
    b=len(l)-1
    mx=max(a,b)
    new_list=[]  #new list to store the ordered elements
    for n in range(mx): #loop until it reaches the last value of the larger list
        if n<=a:
            new_list.append(l[n])
        elif n<=b:
            new_list.append(i[n])

    print new_list
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: I appreciate your constructive critics so i edited the answer.